# Pseudo code for a greedy algorithm for the influence maximization under the independent cascade mode

Tags: arrays, algorithm, graph, pseudocode

I understand the concept behind a greedy algorithm but am still confused about the influence maximization under the independent cascade model and how I would implement the greedy algorithm.

1. read in the data in a loop
2. stick it into a data structure (i.e. arrays for nodes & edges, variables for the node count, edge count, probability, etc),
3. loop through the nodes and edges using the algorithm storing the output values into another array, and finally
4. loop to print out the results of your output array.

I am looking for pseudo code to understand the overall approach to creating this program.

I had found pseudo code for a greedy algorithm but I'm not sure I'm hoping to be able to create a working project once I am pushed in the right direction.

[Link to prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmVOO.png)

[Link to Greedy Algorithm Pseudo code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q1qI.png)

I have this as far as the greedy algorithm goes:

{

Open file (graph.txt)

Readln (n, m, k)

i = 1

while (i <= n)

Readln(nodes[i], vert[i], probability[i])

end

}